# Named parameters order has sense for MySql .Net data provider?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I found that in my project order of named parameter has sense.

I call this procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`TestProc` (
in myText varchar (5),
in myText2 varchar (100)
)
BEGIN

END
```

If I add parameters like this:

```
    command.CommandText = "testProc";
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("myText2", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("myText", "bbbb");
```

I get "Data too long" exception. Also I can't reproduce this in test project.

Any thoughts?

---

I found the cause. Looks like bug in MySql .Nat Data Provider.
To reproduce the bug you need to call this not under the root user.

**Conclusion: MySql.Data version 6.2.3.0.
Order of named parameter has sense If you call procedure with non root db account**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer that I get from MySql bugtracker:

Reggie Burnett

> I don't believe this is a bug.  I
>   believe your test user doesn't have
>   the privs to see the body of the proc.
>   Please login to MySQL using the
>   commandline client and the test user
>   account.  Do a "show create procedure"
>   on your proc.  If the body is null you
>   need to use the "use function
>   bodies=false" option and pass in the
>   parameters in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the parameters don't have to match the columns but the placeholders:

```
INSERT INTO testproc (mytext, mytext2) VALUES (?mytext, ?mytext2)
```

I suppose if you use unnamed parameters:

```
INSERT INTO testproc (mytext, mytext2) VALUES (?, ?)
```

the order does matter.

I always used the former option but with:

```
command.Parameters.Add("?mytext2", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")
command.Parameters.Add("?mytext", "bbbb")
```

Don't know if it makes any difference to AddWithValue()

**Update: Just noticed that your parameters are missing a questionmark. That will be the problem. Add a questionmark to both, your query and your parameters.**

Comment: I don't add parameters to query text. I've just edited my code to show how I call procedure.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't paid enough attention to your first sql bits. It looked like a create table statement so I thought you wanted to query something ;)

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL driver doesn't support named parameters. The name of the parameters are ignored, and they are applied in the order that you put them in the parameter collection.

Comment: @Orsol: There may be differences between drivers. Are you using the same database server, the same driver and the same way to connect in the test project?

Comment: All same. Database is not same, but I think it doesn't matters