# MySQL not recognizing image

Tags: mysql, web-services, image

I have a client application built in C# which sends an image along with an id to a webservice. The webservice then receives these information and inserts them in a MySQL database. But someone, the webmethod cannot recognize the Image and instead, it is just saving `@icon` in the database....can anyone tell me where I am making an error? Thanks in advance!

```
[WebMethod]
public string sendDataToMySql(string application_id, byte[] buffer)
{
    string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
           "DATABASE=test;" +
           "UID=root;" +
           "PASSWORD=password;";


    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
    connection.Open();
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("", connection);
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE application SET icon='@icon' WHERE application_id='" + application_id +"';";

    MySqlParameter oParam1 = command.Parameters.Add("@icon", MySqlDbType.Blob);
    oParam1.Value = buffer;

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    connection.Close();
    return "Data was inserted successfully!";
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i had to guess anything, it'd be that `SET icon='@icon'` needs to be `SET icon=@icon`.  The former only makes sense if you actually want to insert that string literal.

And the second thing I'd be wondering about is `@icon` vs. `?icon`.  I'm seeing asp.net code on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245210/named-parameters-order-has-sense-for-mysql-net-data-provider) referencing the question mark syntax and [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net-programming-blob.html) referencing the at symbol syntax.

I must confess which would be right for any existing drivers out there.

Comment: using `@icon` instead of `'@icon'` worked! Thanks! I dont know why I did not think of that before...