# Does Parameter Order Matter When Calling MySql Stored Proc From C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a MySql stored proc defined as follows:

```
PROCEDURE `updateClient`(IN firstname varchar(45), IN lastname varchar(45)...
```

I am calling this proc from C# like so:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
...
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("updateClients", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstname", "John");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("lastname", "Doe");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This works fine, but if I transpose the order of the parameters when adding them to the command in C# such that they're not added in the same order as the proc expects them:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("lastname", "Doe");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstname", "John");
```

I then get the wrong values in my input params when they get to the proc (i.e. - firstname="Doe" and lastname="John")

This is odd to me as I expected the C# command parameters to just map to their named counterparts on the MySql side. With MS-SQL it does not matter what order you add the parameters to the command. Is this not the case with MySql or am I missing something else? Thanks

Comment: I think you answered your own questions here, didn't you?

Comment: This could contain the answer to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245210/named-parameters-order-has-sense-for-mysql-net-data-provider As far as I know the MySql connector is able to associate correctly the parameters by their names

Comment: Prefixing question marks on the param names is not valid syntax on the proc side. If I add it only on the C# side, they basically seem to just be ignored. Works exactly as it does without them. But now I see that the accepted answer on that thread was actually to do with permissions on the proc. Checking on that next, that seems promising.

Comment: Granting the permissions to the user also did not help. I am able to retrieve the proc as that user using "SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE", but still the parameter names are ignored and they are handled in the order in which they're passed.

Comment: Do you have `Check Parameters=false` in your connection string? If so, you're enabling MySql.Data functionality that ignores parameter names and requires parameters to be passed in the correct order. You could work around this by switching to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ an alternative OSS implementation that doesn't have this bug.

Comment: Thanks Bradley, I think that's the problem. I believe I had to add this to the connection string because I was getting errors when passing null values to a proc. I will give MySqlConnector a try and see if that solves both issues.